# JIRA extension that adds rich text for Description field of issue

Tags: plugins, jira

Is there any Jira extension or plugin that adds rich text for Description field, for comments of issue? Something like COnfluence style.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need an extension for that. Since JIRA version 3.4 it ships with two two renderers. You just need to enable them as admin.

- Atlassian Wiki Renderer (what you want, supports Confluence wiki notation)
- Default Text Renderer.

Check this two pages

[Configuring Rich-Text Renderers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-renderers-938847270.html)

[Editing Rich-Text Fields](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/rich-text-editing-938847886.html)

[Content at time of answer: Editing Rich-Text Fields](https://web.archive.org/web/20090328073751/http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/v3.13/renderers_overview.html)

Comment: It's good enough. But what about confluence-like toolbar?

Comment: @Zahar there has been tons of fight even to get these features.  Be happy :/

Comment: Links not working!

Comment: @1cedsoda Updated links

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a Rich Text Editor you could check https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.jiraeditor.jeditor. It is really capable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since JIRA 7.3 rich text editor is the default editor for descriptions and other text fields, including custom fields.

See

- JIRA Server 7.3 blog post http://blogs.atlassian.com/2017/01/jira-server-7-3-power-to-the-admins
- JIRA Server 7.3. release notes https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-7-3-x-release-notes-861181590.html

Cheers,
Ignat.